# Server Side Blazor Asp.Net Identity SignInAsync error : The response headers cannot be modified

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to get the Asp.Net Identity login working through Blazor in the Visual Studio template application it still uses Razor Pages and MVC to login, but can only get it to work on the event `OnInitAsync`, which is not useful because it needs to be done on a button click and not when the page is loading.

My failing code is

```
protected async Task LoginTest()
{
   await _SignInManager.SignInAsync(new ApplicationUser()
   { UserName = "test@test.com" }, true);
   UriHelper.NavigateTo("/", true);
}
```

I get the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderCollection.ThrowIfReadOnly()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderCollection.set_Item(String key, StringValues value)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.ResponseCookies.Append(String key, String value, CookieOptions options)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.ChunkingCookieManager.AppendResponseCookie(HttpContext context, String key, String value, CookieOptions options)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.HandleSignInAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthenticationProperties properties)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInWithClaimsAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, IEnumerable`1 additionalClaims)
at WebApplication3.Pages.Account.Login.RegUser() in C:\Users\david\source\repos\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\Pages\Account\Login.razor:line 28
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

Has anyone had any success in getting this working? As I mentioned I can get it to work if I put the above function inside the `OnInitAsync` method but it's no good doing it there.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No since I found this GitHub issue https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11411, I ended up creating a work-around solution using the post-redirect-get approach. In the post I encrypted a login token with the user details and passed it to another page as a get with the token in the parameter, then I read the encrypted token and login the user.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was trying to use _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync in a Razor Component's ViewModel. I swear I had it working correctly, but after some refactoring, I couldn't get it to work. I tried to revert and it wasn't working. It was a late-night... Then I realized it is supposed to done in a Razor Page, not a Razor Component.

Comment: @DavidHawkins plase can yot tell me how did you encrypt the login information to pass in get call? thanks

Comment: It seems you cannot write anything to the headers after the Blazor app is up (like cookies). This I think is because there is no request/response. The only response is the response that served the initial page. Writing cookies should be done using javascript interop - but this should fix the RefreshSignInAsync because it is simply a bug.

Comment: @DavidHawkins Please can you share the code you mentioned in your comment. I tried to implement this, but had the same exception even when calling `_SignInManager.SignInAsync` inside `OnInitializedAsync` (I assume that's the same as what you mean by `OnInitAsync` as I don't see a method with that name to override). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After reading [David Hawkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1761392/david-hawkins) post and some digging, I found a workaround solution as he described on https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13601#issuecomment-679870698. Simple and effective.

In the proposed solution, there is no encryption of the user/password details in the middleware, as it stays on the server.

As of now (April 2021) it doesn't seems if ASP.Net Core 5 and Identity supports Blazor calling `SignInManager`'s `*SignIn` methods. By the time it is called, the HTTP headers have already been send and cannot be modified/appended too.

Comment: Thanks. I raised this issue, just on the offchance that it happens. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35551

Comment: @Webreaper, I agree with your issue raised and I'm glad it is not just me who have this issue. It got worse for me as my project moved from Blazor Server to Blazor WASM. I eventually build all of the Identity Server UI MVC into Blazor components and with a lot of middleware code manage to implement a seamless UI and handle auth redirects in Blazor with backend API calls to speak to Identity Server (not a nice experience).

Comment: There might be a potential workaround for this - see this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68889811/can-we-consume-a-blazor-component-as-a-web-component-within-a-regular-non-blazor
and this article by the inimitable Mr Sainty: https://chrissainty.com/using-blazor-components-in-an-existing-mvc-application/

Comment: Unfortunately it not works in Firefox (in Chrome, Opera, Edge - Ok). Anybody, please, do you know universal (including Firefox) solution for Blazor Server?

Comment: @JJ-za everything related to Identity like SignIn, Login, .. should stay in MVC as it is the most secure way to handle it.

Comment: @MarchalPT, MVC is a UI framework and the same can be achieved, and as secure, using REST API. Blazor doesn't necessary means the authentication takes place client side, and once you have a JWT token in the client there is no difference regardless what UI framework you are using.

Answer (score -3):

I found this related GitHub issue http://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11411

I ended up creating a work-around solution using the post-redirect-get approach. In the post I encrypted a login token with the user details and passed it to another page as a get with the token in the querystring, then I read the encrypted token and login the user.

Comment: Can you please share the solution which you did ? It's to helpful fro me.