# Is it possible to embed a remote self-contained blazor component inside an MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an admin app based on Blazor Server and an ASP.NET MVC client app. Both are hosted on separate servers. I would like to embed a blazor calendar component from the admin app into my client app with minimal Blazor overhead. The blazor component will have input parameters and output parameter. Ideally, the component should be similar to an embedded video player or audio player which can be inserted into any page.

Is this possible in ASP.NET? If so, how is it done?

Comment: here's  a related case may help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68889811/can-we-consume-a-blazor-component-as-a-web-component-within-a-regular-non-blazor